# DKIM 'Fail' (bad signature)

Tags: php, email, authentication, amazon-ses

I am using Amazon SES to send emails and using their Easy DKIM service. I have set up three CNAME records on my domain according to the instructions at the Amazon setup. The DKIM shows as "success" so clearly Amazon thinks that the DKIM records are correctly setup.

When I am trying to send messages to my email (an @gmail.com) the DKIM shows as 'FAIL'with domain 'mail.karkortet.se'. Some services have also reported a (bad signature) after the error.

Mail-tester.com does not give me any errors apart from the fact that it says that there are two DKIM signatures. This is as expected with Amazon SES however, as noted per their documentation.

What can I do? As far as I can see everything is correctly configured, however gmail is still reporting as DKIM 'FAIL'. Outlook does the same. Online services that verify DKIM using selector (7m6sh5wu4ruot5wpulatl6burnssh43d) and domain (mail.karkortet.se), such as [this](https://dmarcian.com/dkim-inspector/) one, verify the DKIM record as correct as well.

Domain is verified in Amazon SES and no emails are added. A mail FROM-address is not set.

Comment: Tried to send email via Amazon SES domains list - the email passed DKIM verification.